# .notDetermined to wait for a response from user

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I'm currently experimenting with `CLLocation` and i recently came across `authorizationStatus`. I want to show one view if the user allows the app to use location services, and another one if he/she don't. It works as I want it to, except `.notDetermined`. If I insert it in my `.denied`-block and press "Allow when in use", I can't render the "allow" page but rather have to restart the app to render it. It's also the other way around if I put it in my `.accesWhenInUse`-block and press "deny". So my question is, what is a good practice to do with this command? Ideally I want the app to wait until the user actually does a choice and load it from there, but since `.notDetermined` is required to handle i'm a bit lost.

My init location func so far:

```
   private func initLocation() {
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {

        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways  :
            locationManager.delegate = self
            locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            break

        case .notDetermined:
            break

        case .restricted, .denied:
            print("well this is awkward..")
            view.addSubview(noLocationTextView)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                noLocationTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 210),
                noLocationTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 210),
                noLocationTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
                noLocationTextView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
                ])

            noLocationTextView.text = "Well we're going to need your location"
            break
        }
      }

    }
```

I've extracted `.notDetermined` to its own case right now. 
So the question is, how do I handle this so that the app waits and loads the proper view when a choice is made?

Comment: Rather than using the completion block, use the [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423701-locationmanager?changes=_2)

Comment: You are doing it right. When the authorisation is `notDetermined`, you can either ask for permission again or let the user proceed using other parts of the app. Just one thing: the `case .notDetermined` should be the last case, it's the `default` case here.

Comment: @Paulw11 that did the trick, thank you!

Comment: @regina_fallangi I added the code into the delegate method Paul suggested. For now, I have default(notDetermined as you said) as empty and it works so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Paulw11 I managed to fix this by using the [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanagerdelegate/1423701-locationmanager?changes=_2). So instead of using my `initLocation()` I used this:

```
 func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        switch status {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:

            goToLocationSettings.removeFromSuperview()
            noLocationContainer.removeFromSuperview()
            break
        case .denied, .restricted:
            print("well this is awkward..")
            view.addSubview(noLocationContainer)

           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                noLocationContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.heightAnchor),
                noLocationContainer.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.widthAnchor),
                ])

            noLocationContainer.insertSubview(goToLocationSettings, at: 3)

            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                goToLocationSettings.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
                goToLocationSettings.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
                goToLocationSettings.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 200),
                goToLocationSettings.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
                ])

            break

        default:

            break
        } 
}
```

This way `.notDetermined` is `default` which does nothing until the user made a choice, as I wanted. It also changes in real-time so if I deny access to location and then grants it when the app is running it just updates the view and shows the content. Hope this helps someone with a similar problem!